# FIlter with dataAtributtes

Tags: javascript

how i can make a filter cards with cards
this my button with category,cards had same categories.I need algorythm, when i choose my category i need see only cards with choosed category
cards had same category with this buttons

```
const categoriesData = categories.map(function(categoryName) {
    return `<li class="hashtag">
         <a href="#" data-category="${categoryName}">${categoryName}</a>
        </li>`;
}).join(``);
  
categoriesList.innerHTML = ``;
categoriesList.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, categoriesData);

function onCategoriesListClick(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  
    const button = evt.target.closest(`a`);
    let activeButton = false;

    if (!button) {
      return;
    }
**if(button.hasAttribute('data-category') == cardsData.hasAttribute('data-category')){
    activeButton = false;
    if(button.hasAttribute('data-category') != cardsData.hasAttribute('data-category')){
        activeButt
    }
}** - there i need algorythm to filter cards


};
  
categoriesList.addEventListener('click', onCategoriesListClick);
```

Comment: Try [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).